# How much RAM can I add to my macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have a 2008 macbook with a 2.1 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo.

I am in the process of upgrading to Lion.

I currently have 2GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM

What's the maximum amount of RAM I can put in and it have an effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[everymac.com](http://everymac.com) is an awesome source for this kind of information. They've got detailed specs for all Macs.*

[Yours](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/stats/macbook-core-2-duo-2.1-white-13-early-2008-penryn-specs.html) is listed as **supporting a maximum of 6GB of RAM**. Technically, Apple says that this computer only supports 4, but it has been proven to actually support 6:

> Apple officially supports a maximum of 4 GB of RAM but third-parties
>   have been able to upgrade the system to 6 GB of RAM using one 2 GB and
>   one 4 GB memory module.

You can buy a [6GB kit](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/5300DDR2S6GP/) from OWC, a great company, for $120.

If you use a lot of apps and regularly run up against the edge of your available memory, everything you add will make a difference; the computer can take advantage of all of it. However, since you've currently got 2, you should consider if 4 will be enough or if you want all 6.

*In additon to Everymac, I recommend the app [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/) for Mac and iOS (free). It has detailed info and specs for all Mac models.

Comment: Nice, just bought the OWC 6GB kit

Comment: I upgraded an old iMac to 6GB this way, it worked out great.

Answer (score 4):

Your Macbook supports up to 6GB of RAM.

Apple states that it's 4GB, but OWC continuously checks the max. supported RAM of Apple's computers.

See this list [here](http://eshop.macsales.com/memory/maxram):

[image]

Comment: I confirm by first-hand experience that the MacBook Late 2008 Unibody's support at least 8 GB of RAM (I haven't tried more).

Answer (score 2):

It officially supports 4GB of RAM, but has been reported to [actually take 6GB](http://www.barefeats.com/mbpp11.html). Lion is a 64-bit OS, and will use all of the RAM you give it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right and [that's your MacBook Model](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP5) then the maximum is 4GB.

And if it does have an effect or not depends how much free memory you have now. But usually it's a good thing to upgrade if you use the latest OS X versions.